# prove or disprove: if a domain has complete factorizations, the accp holds

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Prove or disprove (with a counterexample) the following: if $R$ is an integral domain where every nonzero nonunit can be written as a product of irreducible elements, the ascending chain condition on principal ideals holds.

I think it might be false. I tried proving it as follows, but the reasoning below doesn't work as we can always factor the $r_i's$ and $a_1$ but I don't think I get a contradiction. Suppose $R$ is an integral domain such that every nonzero nonunit can be written as a product of irreducible elements. Suppose $R$ does not satisfy the ascending chain condition on principal ideals. Then we may find a strictly increasing chain of principal ideals $(a_1)\subsetneq (a_2)\subsetneq (a_3)\subsetneq\cdots$ in $R$. In particular, none of the $a_i$'s is a unit and we may assume none is zero (by removing the $a_1$ if it's zero). So $a_1 \in (a_2)\Rightarrow a_2 = r_1a_1$ for some nonzero nonunit $r_1$ (as $(a_1)\neq (a_2)$ and $(a_2)\neq (0)$).  Then $a_2 \in (a_3)\Rightarrow a_3 = r_2 a_2 = r_2 r_1 a_1,$ and by similar reasoning $r_2$ is a nonzero nonunit. Continuing this process, $a_n = r_{n-1}r_{n-2}\cdots r_1 a_1.$

Is there some "relatively simple" counterexample?

Comment: in fact, the statement is false, but the examples I know of are a bit involved; see eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941913/example-of-fd-not-satisfying-accp) for some discussion. if you have access to sci-hub, [here](https://sci-hub.do/10.1017/s0305004100048532) is a link to the paper of Anne Grams mentioned in rschwieb's answer, which includes a complete construction and proof of a counterexample